# Should there be ground vias on a TVS diode GND if positioned right next to a DC jack?

Tags: tvs, via, ground-plane

Say you have a TVS diode which is right next to the DC jack, would you want to have ground vias around the GND pad of the TVS diode, or would you want to avoid vias here because the current would just go straight from the TVS GND pad on the top layer to the top layer GND pad and pin on the DC jack, then to the barrel connector of the AC adapter, which is where the return current will be going anyway? I believe it would go directly back to the ground ring of the barrel connector of the AC adapter anyhow, is that correct? And then back to ground of the electrical system that is powering it? I'm not exactly sure where the ground current would go after it goes through the diode, I just assume it would go directly back to the DC jack where it came from.

I'm sure that regardless, most of the current would go directly on the top layer from the TVS GND to the DC jack GND, but possibly if there were vias, they might obstruct current flow a little or transfer some current to the ground plane layer and then back to the DC jack GND which is also connected to the ground layer? I'm not sure exactly how it would all work, so an explanation of how the ground current would flow, and whether or not vias would be appropriate around the TVS GND pad is what I'm asking.

[image]

Comment: It depends not only on the threat but also the potential energy of the surge threat (that could turn the TVS into an unwanted victim) and the actual potential victim of the surge threat that you were originally trying to protect. Once you decide this, you might answer your own question.